# Javascript toUpperCase() a part of string?

Tags: javascript

I want to use the `toUppercase()` method to upper-case a part of my string:

For example:

```
hello javascript
```

to:

```
hello JAVAscript
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not use `.replace()`?

Comment: do you want to uppercase the second word? also show your attempt.

Comment: No i want to upper case a special part of my string

Comment: So where did you get stuck? How do you determine which part of the string you wish to convert to uppercase?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For example character number 2 and 3 and 4 and 5 of any string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Change the case to a part of a word is difficult. Is the string the same every time? Will there always be a space? If so, then you can use `.slice()` or `.split()` to separate the string into parts. You can then use `.toUpperCase()` on those parts.

Comment: Typically, you need some kind of token to signify which part of the string should be capitalized.  If you know the indices of the characters, you could just substring and replace.

Comment: Thanks to answer my problem solved by your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of a specific formatting for specific characters in a string.

```js
function makeUpper(s) {
  var parts = [];
  parts[0] = s;
  parts[1] = s.slice(0, 2);
  parts[2] = s.slice(2, 6);
  parts[3] = s.slice(6);
  parts[2] = parts[2].toUpperCase();
  console.log(parts);
  return parts[1] + parts[2] + parts[3];
}

$(function() {
  $("#myInput").blur(function() {
    $("#myOutput").html(makeUpper($(this).val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input: <input type="text" id="myInput">
<br /> Output: <span id="myOutput"></span>
```